# Maximum memory usage reached using Gaussian Process scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have to build a surrogate model for an aircraft engine in order to predict thrust and SFC according to 4 parameters : Altitude, Mach number, Throttle and Power off take. I have a CSV table with all those parameters plus the respective thrust and SFC. When I try to feed the Gaussian Process with this table it quickly reaches the maximum memory usage of my computer and it eventually freeze completely.
What should I do to avoid this ? 
I tried to play with the hyper parameters but without success and I can't reduce my number of points. 
This is what a typical line in my table looks like : (there is 9000 lines in total)

```
Z   M    Trottle    POT     THR     TSFC
200 0.3  0.295      20000   12497   0.0000236
```

The Python code

```
    regr_sfc = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(theta0=15,thetaL=8.,thetaU=100.)
    regr_thr = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(theta0=15.,thetaL=8.,thetaU=100.)                
    thr_surrogate = regr_thr.fit(xy, thr)
    sfc_surrogate = regr_sfc.fit(xy, sfc)
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there any value in building the model in sections? For example, modeling M = [0.0 to 0.4] and then M=[0.3 to 0.7] and then M=[0.6 to 1.0]?  Something similar to this idea would reduce the number of data points for each section of the total model. Note that I have included some overlap in the data ranges.